# jQuery Plugins for Financial Reporting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Any suggestions on some `jQuery` plugins for reporting a `balance sheet` or `income statement`?

Comment: Do you mean "jQuery plugin to display tabular data?(some sort of grid)"

Comment: Yes to the tabular date, however with more complex features such as hiding and displaying accounts or sub accounts let's say.

Comment: This is not relevant. Jquery doesn't have much to do with any sort of financial reporting, accounting or business applications. You would have to do a bit of math and build your own library I believe (unfortunately).

Comment: Googling found http://jquerygrid.net/

Comment: it's `jQuery` not `Jquery` mister

Comment: @Ravindra This question is off-topic. Rather than editing, how about voting to close?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan voted to close ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look Ember Table at http://opensource.addepar.com/ember-table

> Ember table allows you to render very large data sets by only
>   rendering the rows that are being displayed. It is written as an ember
>   component with an API that is easy to understand and extend.